# Show that the group $ S_n $ is generated by two sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Show that the group $ S_n $ is generated by $ \{(1,2), (1,2,3,...,n) \} $ and also $ \{(1,2), (2,3,...,n)\}$.

How I should start, maybe use induction?

Comment: Whatever the real idea or insight behind the proof, on the technical level it will probably be induction anyway. I think that if you dig deep enough, most facts about finite groups ultimately use induction.

Comment: So I should use induction? Because @Prahlad Vaidyanathan below said, that it isn't good way.

Comment: You should use your common sense. You should first understand yourself why the group is generated by these sets. You don't need induction for that. hardmath's answer is a good explanation. Induction is only necessary when you write the proof rigorously.

Comment: Look in comments below anwer @hardmath, my last but one comment is good ?

Comment: Well, the calculations are correct (provided the permutations are multiplied "left to right"). But I'm not sure you quite got the hint about conjugation.

Comment: Could you show beginning proof?

Comment: Maybe $S_3$ is too small to notice the general idea. Can you calculate the following in $S_5$: $(1,2,3,4,5)^{-1} (1,2) (1,2,3,4,5)$ ?

Comment: Also, maybe this will be useful too: $(1,2,3,4,5)^{-2} (1,2) (1,2,3,4,5)^2$. Can you see what I'm driving at?

Comment: No :(, I don't see.

Comment: Well, have you calculated two products that I mentioned? What are the results?

Comment: I can't calculate $ (1,2,3,4,5)^{-2}(1,2)(1,2,3,4,5)^2 $

Comment: OK, put this one on hold for a while. But what about the other one, $(1,2,3,4,5)^{-1}(1,2)(1,2,3,4,5)$? Please, write down the answer explicitly, so that we have something solid before discussing general ideas.

Comment: $$ (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)^{-1}(1,2)(1,2,3,4,5) = {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 3 4 5 1}^{-1} \circ {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 1 3 4 5}\circ{1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 3 4 5 1}^{1} $$ Or maybe $$ (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)^{-1}(1,2)(1,2,3,4,5) = {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 1 2 3 4 5}^{-1} \circ {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 1 3 4 5}\circ{1 2 3 4 5 \choose 1 2 3 4 5}^{1} $$

Comment: It's the first one. But you've just re-written the expression, you haven't actually multiplied.

Comment: $$ {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 3 4 5 1} \circ {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 1 3 4 5} = {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 3 2 4 5 1} $$ $$  {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 3 2 4 5 1} \circ {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 3 4 5 1} = {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 4 5 1 3}$$ Right?

Comment: No. You didn't take the inverse of the first factor, $(1,2,3,4,5)$. That $^{-1}$ is there for a reason. It seems to me that at the moment you'd benefit a lot from doing some exercises on pure computations, and only then move on to proving general statements such as your original question.

Comment: ok, so I should compute this?

Comment: You should get comfortable with computations, then you should get comfortable with the notion of conjugation, up to the point when you would compute things like $(1,2,3,4,5)^{-1}(1,2)(1,2,3,4,5)$ in your head. Then you'll be ready to prove the statement in your question.

Comment: And yes, you should compute $(1,2,3,4,5)^{-1}(1,2)(1,2,3,4,5)$. The correct result is a transposition. You should also compute $(1,2,3,4,5)^{-2}(1,2)(1,2,3,4,5)^2$. That will also be a transposition. Then you should think and understand why the results are the way they are. Then your own question will become clearer to you.

Comment: Ok, but I should compute this, if up compute is bad?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: I think, that you don't understand me. My method to compute this example. Firsly I would calculate $ (1,2,3,4,5)^{-1} = {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 3 4 5 1}^{-1} \Rightarrow {2 3 4 5 1 \choose 1 2 3 4 5} \Rightarrow {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 5 1 2 3 4}$ to this point is well?

Comment: Next step is: $$ {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 5 1 2 3 4} \circ {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 1 3 4 5} = {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 1 5 2 3 4} $$ ok?

Comment: In prev comment I calulate $ \gamma = f^{-1} \circ r $ In this comment I want calulate $ \gamma \circ f $, so: $$ {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 1 5 2 3 4} \circ {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 3 4 5 1} = {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 5 2 3 4 1 } $$

Comment: OK, this is  alright, although now you multiply right-to-left, but it's not really important. So you see, the result is equal to (1,5). It's a transposition. Now you need to understand in general what will be the result if you compute this: $(1,2,\ldots,n)^{-k} (1,2) (1,2,\ldots,n)^k$.

Comment: And then you should be able to follow hardmath's answer.

Comment: ok, but what I should calulate $ (1,2,3,4,5)^{−2}(1,2)(1,2,3,4,5)^2 $ Firtly $$ {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 3 4 5 1} \circ {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 3 4 5 1} = {1 2 3 4 5 \choose 2 3 4 5 1}^2 $$ ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10226/discussion-between-dan-shved-and-mat)

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the observation that it suffices to generate all transpositions (cycles of length 2), since these will certainly suffice to generate the rest of $S_n$.

Observe what happens when you conjugate the transposition $(1,2)$ with the longer cycle.  How can we generalize this to get more transpositions?

A couple of facts are useful before attempting such a proof:

(1) Every permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles.

(2) Every cycle can be written as a product of transpositions.

Comment: I don't know, I just start learn permutations and transpositions ;). So induction is bad idea?

Comment: Induction in group theory is (usually) only useful if the group you are working with has "enough" normal subgroups. In this case, $S_{n-1}$, while a subgroup of $S_n$ is not normal, so it might not help to use induction.

Comment: In what class are you studying permutations and transpositions?

Comment: @hardmath I know the facts from your answer, but I don't know how I should begin prove.

Comment: Do you know what it means to "conjugate" in a group?  Given two group elements $g,h$ (permutations in this case) multiplying $ghg^{-1}$ can be called conjugating $h$ by $g$.  See what happens when you do this with the two permutations you started with.

Comment: I understand the task and your hint, but I don't know how I must use it.

Comment: So literally, what do you get when you do the task? Compute, please.

Comment: When I will solve the task, I would do next tasks.

Comment: For example condier $ S_3 $ generated by this sets $$ e = (1 \ 2)(1 \ 2) $$ $$ (1\ 2) = (1 \ 2)$$ $$ (1 \ 3) = (1 \ 2)(1 \ 2\ 3)$$ $$ (2 \ 3) = (1 \ 2 \ 3)(1 \ 2) $$ $$ (1 \ 2 \ 3) = (1 \ 2 \ 3) $$ $$ (1 \ 3 \ 2) = (1 \ 2)(1 \ 2 \ 3)(1 \ 2) $$

Comment: But unfortunately I don't know prove this :(. Could you show me proof for first set?