# Generators of symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

How can you prove that $S_n$ is generated by $(1\space 2)$ and $(1\space 2\space 3\space ... \space n))$ for $n\geq 2$?

Comment: Begin by looking at $$(123\ldots n)(12)(123\ldots n)^{-1}$$

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470557/show-that-the-group-s-n-is-generated-by-two-sets

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- show (or be convinced of the fact) that $S_n$ is generated by permutations of $i$ and $j$; so you should prove that they are in your generated subgroup of $S_n$
- $(i\,j)$ can be obtained from combining permutations $(i \, i+1)$
- as per the comment above, look at what happens if you apply $s = (1\,2\ldots n)$ $m$ times (i.e. $s^m$), then $t = (1 \, 2)$, and then $s^{-1}$ $m$ times (i.e. $s^{-m}$).

You should get there.

Comment: I hope so :), thanks!