# How to prove you can reach all permutations just by switching two numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

Specifically, we have $\{-1, +1\}^{2N}$ where we have $N$ +1's and $N$ -1's. How can we show that by switching two numbers of **opposite** sign we can reach all possible permutatations?

For example, if N=2, we might start off at 
$$\{1, 1, -1, -1\}$$ 
and we make one swap and end up at 
$$\{-1, 1, -1, 1\}$$

I think it's pretty obvious that it is possible to reach all permuations, but I am stuck on how I can show that? I have two ideas

1. Somehow show that if you can go from -1 in first N positions and +1 in latter N positions to vice versa, then it must be possible to reach all states in between?
2. I tried to use induction, but it's still not a solid proof.

Comment: It suffices that you can always reach $\{-1, \ldots, -1, +1, \ldots, +1\}$ by swapping. And that can be done by swapping each $+1$ in the first half with a $-1$ in the second half.

Comment: Have a look here: the switch of two elements are the generators of the symmetric group $S_n$ (i.e. the group of permutations of $n$ elements): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/711018/532409 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1174965/532409 and also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/470557/532409

Comment: mrc_ntn, unfortunately I have no idea what groups are.

@MartinR ok, but from there how do I show that I can reach all possible permutations?

Comment: If you can reach $P_0 = \{-1, \ldots, -1, +1, \ldots, +1\}$ from any permutation $P$, then you can each $P$ from $P_0$ by reversing the steps...

Comment: @MinYoung Kim: OK no groups... alternatively do you know what a matrix is? are you familiar with this concept of permutation matrix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix

Comment: matrices yes, permutation matrix no, but it seems straightforward, just identity matrix with columns permuted to get desired outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subset of a set of generalized transpositions $$\{(1,a_1),(2,a_2),\dots,(2n-2,a_{2n-2}),(2n-1,2n)\}$$ with $i\lt a_i$, to set each bit of the permutation one at a time.

Comment: From what I gather on wikipedia, the transposition (x, y) means swap the elements at position x and y. So if we start at $X=\{1, 1, -1, -1\}$ does the $i<a_i$ mean do (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)  on X? Some states can't be reached just by one swap on X, how do we account those? For example to get to $\{-1, -1, 1, 1\}$ you need two swaps.

Comment: No. If the destination permutation is to be say{ $-1,-1,1,1$}, first swap a '$-1$' with the first '$+1$' (it doesn't matter which one we use) to get {$-1,1,1,-1$}, and then place the second digit.

Comment: So a proof might say, "by applying transpositions taken from the set above, we can reach all possible permutations of $\{-1, +1\}^{2N}$?. But I am still not sure why this is enough to prove the claim "we can reach all possible permutations". Or is this enough?

Comment: You can reach all permutations with N of each of '$\pm 1$'. Without that criteria, you can't, as you won't have enough of one of the types.